# Create a zip file and download it

Tags: php, download, zip

I am trying to download a 2 files by creating the zip file on local-server.the file is downloaded in zip format but when i try to extract it.it gives error: 
**End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zip file, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zip file comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.**

the following code i am using for this:

```
 <?php
$file_names = array('iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf','iMUST Product Information Sheet.pdf');

//Archive name
$archive_file_name=$name.'iMUST_Products.zip';

//Download Files path
$file_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Harshal/files/';


zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
        //echo $file_path;die;
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);
        //echo $file_path.$files,$files."

    }
    $zip->close();
    //then send the headers to force download the zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}




?>
```

i checked the values of all variables which are passing into the function,all are fine.so please look this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked, whether the ZIP file on your server machine is valid? Also, you may do well to erase the ZIP file once you're done with it, because otherwise it will clutter your server HD.

Comment: @ATaylor,i am running it on local-server.

Comment: You have a space at the beginning of your file, before the `<?php`. If that's in the real file and not a cut/paste error, that will corrupt the data.

Comment: @david,i removed those spaces but still giving same error.

Comment: Please refer this answers [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603851/how-to-create-a-zip-file-using-php-and-delete-it-after-user-downloads-it/17399319#17399319][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603851/how-to-create-a-zip-file-using-php-and-delete-it-after-user-downloads-it/17399319#17399319

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Add `Content-length` header describing size of zip file in bytes.

```
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile("$archive_file_name");
```

Also make sure that there is absolutely no white space before `<?` and after `?>`. I see a space here:

↓

```
 <?php
$file_names = array('iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf','iMUST Product Information Sheet.pdf');
```

Comment: Content-length shouldn't be necessary, the server should automatically use chunked encoding.

Comment: @kuba, not working..!!and there is no space in my opening and closing tags.

Comment: Can you compare ZIP files on server-side and client-side? Are they identical?

Comment: yes ,on server side the length of zip file is 226 bytes,and on client side its 1.2 mb.if there is some matter of size than plz give me the exact code for the size of content-length

Comment: server side 226 bytes and client 1.2mb? not the other way round??

Comment: i just check on local by compressing the files,and it gives size of 1.2 mb,but the file i am getting from server after download it gives the size of 226 bytes.

Comment: OK, please try with `Content-length`. I provided an example.

Comment: so now it gives the zip file of length 420 bytes,but still giving same error.

Comment: OK, it seems to me, that ZIP file isn't completely written to disk before accessed with `readfile()`. Please add, for the sake of testing only, `sleep(5);` before `readfile("$archive_file_name");`.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, that is very unlikely: `$zip` functions are disk synchronous, there is no concurrent process performing `addFile`.

Comment: I am just trying to help. It doesn't cost much to check `sleep()`. :]

Comment: @kuba ,still giving same size of files.

Comment: sorry, I'm out of hints then... maybe consider using different zip handling library.

Comment: So, the code needs some basic syntax revisions:
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); needs to be header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$archive_file_name);
and
readfile("$archive_file_name"); needs to be readfile($archive_file_name);

Comment: No it does not. Please consult http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php Variables are substituted in strings and I didn't want to change original code (not to confuse OP).

Comment: The solution still is the correct approach, however I suggest using single apostrophes instead of double, it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 15):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$tmp_file = 'assets/myzip.zip';
    if ($zip->open($tmp_file,  ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
        $zip->addFile('folder/bootstrap.js', 'bootstrap.js');
        $zip->addFile('folder/bootstrap.min.js', 'bootstrap.min.js');
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Archive created!';
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=files.zip');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        readfile($tmp_file);
   } else {
       echo 'Failed!';
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! and this works for me, because I have missing the exact path for the temp file. and my error was this ErrorException-ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied

Answer (score 7):

```
// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

I found this soludtion [here](https://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/) and it work for me

Answer (score 6):

One of the error could be that the file is not read as 'archive' format. check out [ZipArchive not opening file - Error Code: 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503569/ziparchive-not-opening-file-error-code-19). Open the downloaded file in text editor, if you have any html tags or debug statements at the starting, clear the buffer before reading the file.

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("$archive_file_name");
```

Comment: That's right, I think most of the common reasons for getting unsupported file format errors.

Comment: I appreciate the information you shared; it resolved a problem I'd been grappling with for the past few hours. My web server outputs several HTTP headers for security purposes, and these headers were inadvertently inserted into the ZIP file during output. This caused the file to appear invalid, which is likely accurate, but it was essentially a valid file with some extra lines of content that the ZIP decoder couldn't handle. Your assistance was incredibly helpful, and I'd like to express my gratitude – I owe you one, thanks @Avinav :)

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem. For me the issue was with:

```
readfile("$archive_file_name");
```

It was resulting in a out of memory error.

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 292982784 bytes)
```

I was able to correct the problem by replacing readfile() with the following:

```
    $handle = fopen($zipPath, "rb");
    while (!feof($handle)){
        echo fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Not sure if this is your same issue or not seeing that your file is only 1.2 MB. Maybe this will help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: php 8+ i face same error, your solution work for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced exactly the same problem. In my case, the source of it was the permissions of the folder in which I wanted to create the zip file that were all set to read only. I changed it to read and write and it worked.

If the file is not created on your local-server when you run the script, you most probably have the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 0):

> but the file i am getting from server after download it gives the size
>   of 226 bytes

This is the size of a ZIP header. Apparently *there is no data* in the downloaded ZIP file. So, can you verify that the files to be added into the ZIP file are, indeed, there (relative to the path of the download PHP script)?

Consider adding a check on `addFile` too:

```
foreach($file_names as $file)
{
    $inputFile = $file_path . $file;
    if (!file_exists($inputFile))
        trigger_error("The input file $inputFile does not exist", E_USER_ERROR);
    if (!is_readable($inputFile))
        trigger_error("The input file $inputFile exists, but has wrong permissions or ownership", E_USER_ERROR);
    if (!$zip->addFile($inputFile, $file))
        trigger_error("Could not add $inputFile to ZIP file", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The observed behaviour is consistent with some problem (path error, permission problems, ...) preventing the files from being added to the ZIP file. On receiving an "empty" ZIP file, the client issues an error referring to the ZIP central directory missing (the actual error being that there is no directory, and no files).

Comment: Thanks for answer iserni, by putting your code i am getting this error:

Fatal error: Could not add /opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal/files/iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf as iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf from script in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal/ex_sub.php on line 25

Comment: I have modified the code to try to better track the error. Looks like a file naming problem, path problem, or permission error.

Comment: now its giving: Fatal error: The input file /opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal/files/iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf does not exist in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal/ex_sub.php on line 27

Comment: i am sure there is a files ,but wondered why this error comes

Comment: Check the contents of the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Harshal/files/` directory (and the permissions on `Harshal` and `Harshal/files` too). The file may be there, but PHP believes otherwise.

Comment: i already given the permission to Harshal/files.but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path inside `$archive_file_name` is correct and does exist. In your code, you updated the `$archive_file_name` variable by putting an undeclared prefix variable - `$name`.

```
$archive_file_name = $name.'iMUST_Products.zip';
```

If the path is not correct and cannot be found, the created zipped file have nowhere to go to and the two files have nowhere to store to to begin with. The path to the files to be stored should also exist.

Let's assume that you just want to customize the name of the zipped folder to be downloaded that is why there is a `$name` variable to prevent redundant file name. But you have to consider the URI where you run your script.

For example, you're using URI routing, and you load the script at https://sample.co/file-management/download-zipped-111. With your current script, the zipped folder will be stored at `file-management` folder. If it does not exist, you will mostly encounter the error you are experiencing right now.

The solution is to explicitly declare the path to the folder where the zipped file will be stored.

For example, you want to store the zipped file at `Harshal/files/zipped/`. Make sure that this folder exist by creating a folder named `zipped` inside `files` folder and that you have access to write on this folder.

```
$file_names = array('iMUST Operating Manual V1.3a.pdf', 'iMUST Product Information Sheet.pdf');

// $name should be declared before this line
$archive_file_name = $name.'iMUST_Products.zip';

//Download Files path
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Harshal/files/';

zipFilesAndDownload($file_names, $archive_file_name, $file_path);

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names, $archive_file_name, $file_path)
{

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    // WE REUSED THE $file_path VARIABLE HERE THEN ADDED zipped FOLDER
    if ($zip->open($file_path.'zipped/'.$archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit('cannot open <'.$archive_file_name.'>');
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files, $files);
    }
    $zip->close();
    //then send the headers to force download the zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
    header('Content-length: '.filesize($file_path.'zipped/'.$archive_file_name));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}
```

People may suggest - "Why not directly put the full path to the `$archive_file_name` variable?

```
$archive_file_name = $file_path.'zipped/'.$name.'iMUST_Products.zip';
```

If we put it directly to `$archive_file_name` variable, the file that will be downloaded will mostly likely be named `/var/www/Harshal/files/zipped/xxx-iMUST_Products.zip`.