# downloading of file failed via php

Tags: php

I am trying to download a zip file via php
but the downloading breaks in between abruptly
and the code is as follows:

```
<?php
$zip_file="uploads/".$path; 
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="'. $zip_file. '"');
header('Content-length:'. filesize($zip_file));
readfile($zip_file);
exit();
?>
```

The file I am trying to download is in the range of
50-100MB and above in size.Please help me to get through
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check for errors?

Comment: Did you get an error in the form of timeout? I can imagine downloading 50-100 mb might take longer than the maximum execution time as set in your ini file under `max-execution-time`

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225964/create-a-zip-file-and-download-it

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I already use this code every time.

```
<?php
$zip_file = "uploads/".$path;
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zip_file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($zip_file);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the keyword "attachment" in this line:

```
header('Content-disposition: filename="'. $zip_file. '"');
```

So it should be:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. $zip_file. '"');
```

Comment: i have used it already suggest another than this