# how to download all uploaded files from database using single click

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to download all uploaded files from database using single click. is it possible?
I am having a single file download. I modify some changes not working.

Controller

---

```
      $fileInfo = $this->User_Model- 
               >getRows();   
  $file='uploads/files/'.$fileInfo[0] 
       ['file_name'];     
 force_download($file,NULL);
```

Model

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('upload_ins');       

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
```

Suggestion please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action

Comment: You might want to zip all those files and then download just the zip. Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225964/create-a-zip-file-and-download-it

Comment: zip all files then download a zip file