# Download file .ZIP with PHP automatically

Tags: php

I would like to download a file from a folder on my server and automatically start the download without the person seeing the original file link.

Here is my current script, but it downloads an invalid corrupted file.

```
$filename = "dsk.zip";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="./zz/'.$filename.'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("./zz/".$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile("./zz/".$filename);
```

Can you please help me? The file, `dsk.zip`, is in the folder `zz`.

Comment: There are syntax errors in this, like `filename="./zz/'.$filename.'"`. Fix those first.

Comment: `filename="./zz/'.$filename.'"` You cannot define a folder on the user PC, in fact the file name is only a hint and can be ignored by the user in the dialog they will see. SO use a simple `filename=".$filename.'"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a zip file and download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225964/create-a-zip-file-and-download-it)

Comment: The best is to change your **server** folder name or file name but is tricky.
somedomain.com/FOLDER_NAME_/dsk.zip **OR**
somedomain.com/download/dsk-20210902-15464.zip

Comment: What happens with this code? Do you receive an error, if you remove error suppression?

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fix the quotes on this line: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="./zz/'.$filename.'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "dsk.zip"; // this is what you will get from a param (i.e. ?file=dsk.zip) or from DB query

header("Cache-Control: public");

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='zz/'.$file"); 

header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile('zz/'.$file);
```

Comment: What are you suggesting they change here?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.